# why zpopmin time complexity is log n?

Tags: redis

from redis doc:

ZPOPMIN key [count]
Available since 5.0.0.

Time complexity: O(log(N)*M) with N being the number of elements in the sorted set, and M being the number of elements popped.

Removes and returns up to count members with the lowest scores in the sorted set stored at key.

So, my question is, if the list is sorted, why it's take log n, why not O(1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the ***list*** is sorted, why it's take log n, why not O(1)?

If sorted sets were implemented with lists, you could in fact do this in O(1) time per element. However, sorted sets are [implemented](https://jameshfisher.com/2018/04/22/redis-sorted-set.html) (in part) with the [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) data structure, which does insertions and deletions in O(log(N)) time.

Comment: If i have some reference to the start of list, why removing first item takes more than O(1)?we don't need to do resort?

Comment: @yantrab: It's not a list, it's a skip list. Deleting an element requires traversing and potentially modifying O(log N) different layers.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I think deleting smallest element in skip list takes only O(1) because it only needs to delete the first element and then update the head to point to anything the deleted node pointed at.

Comment: @hutabalian: It potentially needs to do that for each of the O(log(N)) [lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#/media/File:Skip_list.svg).

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of accessing any element in the Sorted Set by its score is O(log(N)), hence the command's complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If the smallest node in the skiplist is the highest level node, it cannot be deleted without considering the level points of other nodes