# If Redis Sorted Set is implemented with Skip List, why ZPOPMIN time complexity is O(log n)?

Tags: data-structures, redis, time-complexity, skip-lists

I already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54380988/why-zpopmin-time-complexity-is-log-n) and it isn't what I'm looking for.

As far as I know, deleting first `m` elements in a Skip List containing `n` elements takes `O(m)` or we can say `O(1)` if `m` is not significant. But why `ZPOPMIN` in Redis takes `O(log n)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about the exact implementation that Redis have. However, if the sorted set is implemented using Skip List, the deletion will take `O(log n)`.

From the observation on how the skip lists are built, I think you might get the idea. This is not implemented using a simple single array which will take `O(m)` time to delete the first `m` elements. Instead, it uses multiple arrays (think this as a linked list) and stores the values cleverly to support the add/delete/search in `O(log n)` time.

If it was implemented using a single array, then you are right - the deletion should take `O(m)` time. However, this is not the case for the skip lists. I am trying to add a picture from where you can have an idea of how the lists are being built.

[image]

Hope that helps!

**Update**

Please keep in mind that skip list has levels. The maximum number of levels a skip list can have is `O(log n)`. Let us consider deleting the first three elements here (i.e. 12, 17, 20). To remove 12 first, we have to modify the level 2 and level 1 as we have to point the `- ∞` to 17 in both levels. Once the 12 is removed, then we remove the 17 and do the same here as well. For each deletion, we might have to iterate at most `O(log n)` levels as stated above about the maximum number of levels. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hi, this is my understanding. From your picture, if we want to delete first 3 elements (12, 17, 20), we need to access the 4th element (25) and also the tail to update the related pointers (25's pointer to 20, 25's to 17, and tail's to 17) to be pointed to head. Hence it's O(log n). Am I correct?

Comment: Please check the updated answer and let me know if that helped. :)

Comment: Ok thanks, now I understand why it's O(log n).
Anyway, in your example, I'm just thinking what if instead of deleting the elements one by one from the left, we update the pointers from the 4th element? So, we search for the 4th element, then at level 1-4, since we have `25` at each level, we can just update the `25` left pointers to double-pointing with the head. Then move left one by one to get a value at level 5. Found `17`, update the pointers so the head will just double-pointing with the tail. Then, just remove the pointers at level 5 since it is just pointers between head and tail.

Comment: Still, I have the same question for you. Even if you start from the 4th position, how many levels you need to go in the worst case for pointing the values there to the head? In the example above, if you are starting to point all `25`s to the head, how many `25`s you need to point to the head in the worst case?

Comment: 4 `25`s? And then we don't need to care about 12, 17, and 20 at level 1-4 anymore

Comment: umm ... I think that's not correct. In the worst case, you can have `O(log n)` levels and hence you will have to point all `O(log n)` `25s` to the head.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to say.